# How can I remove default padding in ListWheelScrollView?

Tags: flutter, dart

When there are 3 or more elements ,in this case the first element of ListWheelScrollView in in top of screen.As you see on the picture [image: you can see]

when there are 1 element ,it adds undesired padding to ListWheelScrollView.How can I remove this padding?
[image: undesired padding]

```
ListWheelScrollView(
              controller: FixedExtentScrollController(initialItem: 1),
              physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
              itemExtent: 260,
              perspective: 0.005,

              //squeeze: 0.7,
              diameterRatio: 4,
              children: const [
                  TicketShimmerWidget(),
                  // TicketShimmerWidget(),
                  // TicketShimmerWidget(),
                  // TicketShimmerWidget(),
                ])
```

I have written my code like that.I checked stackoverflow solutions, but they were not so clear for me.

```
    class TicketShimmerWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const TicketShimmerWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context);
    return Container(
      width: size.width,
      height: 260,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(47),
      ),
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 30, vertical: 30),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                Shimmer.fromColors(
                  baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 30,
                    width: 200,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Spacer(),
                Shimmer.fromColors(
                  baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 25,
                    decoration: ShapeDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(22),
                      ),
                    ),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 8,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Shimmer.fromColors(
                  baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 18,
                    width: 130,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Shimmer.fromColors(
                  baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 18,
                    width: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 5,
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Shimmer.fromColors(
                      baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                      highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 18,
                        width: 80,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            const Spacer(),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Shimmer.fromColors(
                  baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                  highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 20,
                    width: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                      color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
                  child: Shimmer.fromColors(
                    baseColor: Colors.grey[300]!,
                    highlightColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 18,
                      width: 80,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post minimal code of `TicketShimmerWidget()`?

Comment: Yes sure I added @Cabdirashiid

Comment: So, When it's a single item, you want it to align on top?

Comment: Yeah.I want to align it on top

Comment: Looks like that's how it's designed, That the middle of the wheel stays center. Maybe try a logic to resize a parent container according to how many cards are in the list. But, then the center of the wheel would shift, would might make it unpredictable.